# JavaScript Puzzle I can't figure out

Tags: javascript, puzzle

This is a kata for code wars, and I can't seem to figure it out. I have never worked with JavaScript before.

I know the answer is probably simple, but I just can't seem to figure out what they are looking for even after many hours of searching. I know that `name` in the `greet` function is not defined, but when I define it, it says it's not the value it's looking for.

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + name;
}
```

Please help and an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use some punctuation to make this bearable. I can't seem to make head or tail out it.

Comment: What's the question? I'm not sure what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: You need to change `name` to `this.name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't really understand what you are looking for but hope this will shed some light : (try on your console)

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + this.name;
}

var p = new Person('jack');

p.greet('sparrow');
```

Comment: Ok I think I've got it, thanks for helping and I will try to be clear in my question asking in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Tyagi gave you an explanation of how to call it but did not show what the actual problem with the code is:

Here's my (very similar) example:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function (otherName) {
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + this.name;
}

var john = new Person("John");

$("#result").text(john.greet("Mike"));
```

and if you [click through to this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnMunsch/52CL4/1/) then you can see it actually working. The difference between the two is simply the change of "name" to "this.name" in the greet() function. You're attaching a new function to every Person object but it doesn't automatically look for the name variable on the object within that function the way it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your question but i will try to explain how it works:

```
// define a function (or class) called 'Person'
function Person(name){
  // add data members 'name' to 'this' pointer which points to current context
    this.name = name;
}

// define a method in 'Person' class 
Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
    //'othername' is an argument which you passed while calling 'greet' method
    //'name' is an data memeber which you declared while creating 'Person' class
    // will return value when you call this method
    return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + this.name;
}

// create a class object
var person = new Person('Mohit');
// call its 'greet' method
// will show an alert 'Hi Bekk, my name is Mohit'
alert(person.greet('Bekk'));
```

[JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/QqnL5/](http://jsfiddle.net/QqnL5/)